# QT - Cloning window "screen" in another window

Tags: qt, qwidget

I have two "QMainWindows" A and B.

A has a pointer to B as a class member (and creates B dynamically on constructor). The program implementation is in two different monitors. 'A' is shown on monitor 'X' and 'B' is shown on monitor 'Y'. 
'A' controls what is shown on 'B', and since I have them in two different monitors, in 'A' I would like to see whats happening on 'B' (kind of a 'screen capture on real time'). Is there any way to do this?

I've thought to make a "QWidget *clone = B->ui->centralWidget;" on 'A's constructor, since in 'B' I have all the information under a 'QWidget centralWidget', but it doesn't seem to work.

Any illuminating idea would be deeply apreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to use `QPixmap::grabWindow` and a QTimer. `QPixmap::grabWindow` returns a QPixmap that you can simply display on e.g. a `QLabel`

Dummy header file for the class that displays

```
class MainWindow: public QMainWindow, public Ui::MainWindow
{
  Q_OBJECT

  public:
  MainWindow(QWidget *parent = NULL);
  ~MainWindow() {};

public slots:
  void update();

private:
  MainWindow2 *window;
  QTimer *timer;
};
```

Implementation

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
{
  setupUi(this);
  window = new MainWindow2;
  window->show();
  timer = new QTimer(this);
  connect(timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(update()));
  timer->start(5000);

}

void MainWindow::update()
{
  if( window ) {
      QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::grabWindow( window->winId() );
      label->setPixmap(pixmap);
  }
}
```

EDIT: added a check to make sure that window is not NULL before asking for its window ID.

This way a screenshot of the child window will be shown on in a QLabel of the parent window and will be updated every 5 seconds (which you can obviously adjust to your needs). Does this cover your use case?

Comment: @moxDac I was wondering if this answer solved your problem or if there is something missing from it? Or maybe the question in any case is no longer of relevance to you?